MATLAB comunication issue with a device (drone TELLO EDU)
I am working on a Project and I need to communicate with a drone (TELLO EDU) via wifi. I would like to receive information while I send commands so I wrote a code using the function parfeval.
This is what I tried:
% Inicializar el dron
tello = ryze() ;

if isempty(gcp('nocreate'))
    disp("Creando pool de workers...");
    parpool;
    disp("COMPLETED");
end

infovuelo = parfeval(@rpyandv, 3, tello, 30);

takeoff(tello) ;

% Introducir distancia de ida y vuelta y velocidad
distance = 1.5 ;
speed = 0.5 ;

% Volar dron ida y vuelta
moveforward(tello,'Distance', distance, 'Speed', speed)
moveback(tello,'Distance', distance, 'Speed', speed)

% Aterrizar el dron y limpiar conexión con él
land(tello) ;
clear tello ;

[ori, vel, tiempo] = fetchOutputs(infovuelo) ;

and this is the rpyandv function:
function [ori, vel, time] = rpyandv(dronename,timereading)
tflying = tic ;

orientation_matrix = [0 0 0] ;
speed_matrix = [0 0 0] ;
time = [] ;

    while toc(tflying)<timereading
        time(end+1) = toc(tflying) ;
        orientation = readOrientation(dronename) ;
        orientation_matrix(end+1,:) = orientation ;
        speedread = readSpeed(dronename) ;
        speed_matrix(end+1,:) = speedread ;
        pause(0.09);
    end

% Apaño de las matrices para dibujarlas
orientation_matrix(1,:) = [] ;
ori = rad2deg(orientation_matrix') ;
speed_matrix(1,:) = [] ;
vel = speed_matrix' ;

clear tello

end

I was expecting to get different values for speed in each dimension as the drone moves but on the graph I only see one value, ZSpeed = 0 represented as a single straight line.
